# Make words from string matching with string bold

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, jquery-autocomplete

I want to make words matching in the string bold. I am using Jquery autocomplete with asp.net mvc. My following code works only if string has single word.

```
label = p.Name.Replace(termToSearch.ToLower(),"<b>" + termToSearch.ToLower() + "</b>"),
```

But doesnt work when I have 2 words matching which are at random position.

E.g When I search Gemini Oil

My Result should be id  **Gemini** Sunflower **Oil**.

Any Ideas

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A single line of Regex can do just that:

```
String term = "Gemini Oil";
String input = "Gemini Sunflower Oil.";
String result = Regex.Replace( input, String.Join("|", term.Split(' ')), @"<b>$&</b>");
Console.Out.WriteLine(result);


<b>Gemini</b> Sunflower <b>Oil</b>.
```

Answer (score 0):

You could just split the search term on each space character and then run the replace multiple times:

```
var terms = termToSearch.split(' ');
foreach (var term in terms) {
    p = p.Name.Replace(term.ToLower(),"<b>" + term.ToLower() + "</b>"),
}
label = p;
```

Comment: Actually I want to do this in single query as there might be big number of products getting returned.